# Difference between style @import and js import in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, import, less

I was reading the source code of ant-design and noticed each component got a [index.ts](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/c6fcc3121758dfe6ac5b50c1b55790eb42b805c5/components/badge/style/index.tsx#L1-L2) and [index.less](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/c6fcc3121758dfe6ac5b50c1b55790eb42b805c5/components/badge/style/index.less#L1-L2) in the style folder. Why js is used here for managing dependencies? What's the difference if I just move it to the less file and use `@import`?

Answer (score 0):

int ant design each component using less file as modular less component it means you less never applying for another components except in `:global` pseudoclass
have a look "react-app-rewire-less-modules"

Comment: Can you explain the differences a little further? "react-app-rewire-less-modules" is just a basic loader setup. Don't see how it relates to this question?